# Persistent ghost image in Windows 10 on top of any white space

Tags: windows, bug

I am experiencing the weirdest of Windows 10 bugs. A small corner of an already closed Chrome session appears on top of any "white space" in all programs. If there is no background, or text/image, an image of the corner of that window shows up as a mosaic. I have no idea how to get rid of this. I have tried rebooting several times, shutting the computer down as well, and nothing happens, the same image appears on top of anything and everything: Chrome, Firefox, Windows explorer, Notepad, Word, etc. The problem seems to be system-wide. Is this a bug or did I make something to make this happen? How do I solve it? This makes my computer almost unusable. Please help.

I'm pasting below a couple of screenshots:

[Bug in Windows Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqFpR.png)
[Bug appears in an Adobe Acrobat PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDlFC.png)

Edit:
I checked this post on another computer, and it turns out that the ghost image doesn't show up in the screenshots I originally uploaded. I'm pasting below a couple of pictures I took with my cellphone:

[Bug appears in Chrome (this post, actually)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSgfy.jpg)
[Bug appears in Adobe Acrobat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFiWu.jpg)

Edit 2:
Additional information: my machine is Microsoft Azure virtual machine.

Comment: Care to edit your screenshots and use a rectangle to identify this ghost window cause it’s not obvious

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I just uploaded photos taken with my cellphone, as the screenshots "hide" the problem

Comment: The fact screenshots hide the problem suggests this is a hardware problem. Does it happen while in Safe Mode?

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is a Microsoft Azure virtual machine, so I don't have access to safe mode, bios, etc.

Comment: Use Autoruns to boot into a minimal configuration, I suspect the problem is the display driver, this ghost image appears before or after you load Chrome?  I would also disable hardware acceleration within Chrome.  You should probably [edit] your question to indicate this is a virtual machine, although I would argue, you could in theory boot into safe mode (I have extensive knowledge of VMs) but not within an Azure infrastructure.

Comment: The problem occurs not only in Chrome, but in all programs, from Windows Explorer to Adobe Acrobat (see the second picture), including Word, Firefox, and even the Task Manager. I will try using Autoruns

Comment: Yes; But the ghost window is Chrome. There is a madness to my suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried getting your windows operating system completely up-to-date with Windows Update and also have you tried updating Google Chrome or re-installing it?